# JavaScript setInterval() freezes my website

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I installed Apache in my Raspberry Pi3 to get a local website.
I have this JavaScript in my `index.php` that I need to refresh every 200ms :

```
function Function()
{
    $.ajax({
        url : 'variable.php',
        data: {action: 'variable'},
        type: 'post',
        success: function(output){
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML= output;
            setInterval(Function(),200);
        }
    });
}
```

In `variable.php`, it's just an output of a command.

But, in 2 minutes, the free memory goes from 220 000 KiB to 40 000 KiB so my website begin to freeze in 10 minutes and I must close my web internet and reopen it.

What's wrong ?

Comment: You have just explained the issue and offered your own solution.. **Problem:** *"the free memory goes from 220 000 KiB to 40 000 KiB"* => **Solution:**  *"I must close my web internet and reopen it"*  Maybe once you run out of memory you're forced to restart the browser to free up the memory? I'm also surprised `setInterval(Function(),200);` works since your choice of function name is `function` and if it would allow you to use that function name I'm pretty sure your interval should be something like this `setInterval(Function,200);`

Comment: I think your setTImeout is very short so it will request many in one second

Comment: Also you set a new interval each time the ajax success has run. Work out how many intervals you will have in 2 minutes. I'm surprised your browser doesn't just crash.

Comment: So how can I refresh with javascript correctly without crashing my browser ?

Comment: Replace `setInterval()` with `setTimeout()` and maybe allow more time.... 200 milliseconds is crazy, if you had to wait 1 second for the data to reload you wouldn't notice much difference from 200 milliseconds but it would make a big difference to the server as it isn't being spammed with requests so much. A fine balance can also depend on the server you're using. If you want live data I would recommend you look into using websockets. One request but is kept open allowing updates and exchange of data.

Answer (score 6):

It becomes more or less an endless recursion problem because in every callback for the XHR you are calling `Function` (because you have parenthesis there, making an invocation and not a reference) as well as setting it to be called every 200ms. You should only pass the reference to the function there, and use `setTimeout()` instead.

```
setTimeout(Function, 200);
```

Also, `Function` is a bad name for a function. It will also clobber the `Function` constructor.

Comment: Or use `setInterval` on the first calling of `Function`

Comment: @NathanP. I would suggest against it, as if some XHRs take a long time the requests will stack up. for some situations though that's appropriate for the design.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "You should only pass the reference to the function there".

Comment: @Zekeriya Look at the example code in the answer. There are no `()` after the function name. If you have them there, you invoke the function when the IP hits that line. Without them, you have a *reference* to that function, a pointer if you will to it. This means that the function is not immediately invoked, but rather `setTimeout()` now has a reference to it to call it later.

Comment: Even I put "setTimeout()" with a 1 second refresh, it's doesn't change the free memory falls.

Comment: @Zekeriya With the reference to the function?

Answer (score 1):

It is a recursive call which should be handled wisely. I recommend you call recursive function on Ajax.Success callback that will help you recall the function if the previous Ajax call succeeded. And you will prevent throttling your server.